# Como enviar dados de uma Activity para um Fragment?

Tags: java, android-fragment, android-activity

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5idF.png)Estou com uma dúvida ja faz um tempo. Quero passar um valor de uma `activity` para um `fragment`, porém, da erro na hora de abrir o `fragment` para ser especifico na hora de receber esse valor, creio eu.

Assim é como seto:

```
estab = "academia";

        MapsFragment_Estab mapsFragment_estab = new MapsFragment_Estab();
        Bundle academia = new Bundle();
        academia.putString("CoordAcademy", estab);
        mapsFragment_estab.setArguments(academia);
```

E assim é como recebo no `fragment`:

```
String CoordAcademy = getArguments().getString("CoordAcademy");
```

[[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]]

Comment: Com prints, dificilmente alguém irá te ajudar. Ao invés disso poste o código em si. Veja: [Como não perguntar](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-nÃo-fazer-perguntas)

Comment: Entendo, sou novo por aqui. Entendi, vlw =D.

Comment: Você está colocando o `String CoordAcademy = getArguments().getString("CoordAcademy");` dentro do método `onCreateView()`? Poste todo o método. Se possível adicione também a mensagem de erro.

Comment: Quanto ao erro da erro no fragment do meu mapa no methodo do onCreate.

Comment: Teria como postar a mensagem de erro que aparece no seu `Log`, no final da pergunta? Porque a princípio a sintaxe está correta.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                            at Fragments.MapsFragment_Estab.onCreate(MapsFragment_Estab.java:27)

Comment: Estou repostando o Oncreate sem os meus comments pra ficar mais limpo:  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        

         String CoordAcademy = getArguments().getString("CoordAcademy");


        getMapAsync(this);
    }

Comment: Printei os erros, acima. Desde já, agradeço a atenção.